# Additional Controller to get the content of single field in Spring Data Rest project

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest

I have my first small spring-data-rest project. Some fields have a xml-content. I need some ideas how to get the content of these fields as xml-output.

I have now:
http://localhost:8084/cn/00058548.xml

```
<record>
<content><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><contentRoot id="00058548">...</contentRoot>]]><content>
<metadata><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><metadataRoot id="00058548">...</metadataRoot>]]><metadata>
<title>xxx</title>
</record>
```

And what I need:

http://localhost:8084/00058548/getField?field=content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<contentRoot id="00058548">...</contentRoot>
```

or ?field=metadata

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadataRoot id="00058548">...</metadataRoot>
```

Is the additional controller the right way for it?

```
@RequestMapping(
            value = "/field/{id}/getField",
            params = "field",
            method = RequestMethod.GET)    
    public ModelAndView getField(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable final String id, @RequestParam final String field ) throws Exception  {
        Record rec = this.recordRepository.findOne(id);
        if ( field.equals("content") ) {
            return new ModelAndView(???,???,rec.getContent());
        } else if ( field.equals("metadata") ) {
            return new ModelAndView(???,???,rec.getMetaData());
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Wrong field value!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm sure you can achieve what you're after, but if you don't want to use REST why are you using spring-data-rest?

Comment: thanks for asking, i need CRUD operations over the data as main thing, but i also need some additional data representations

Answer (score 0):

i think i've got it:

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/field/{id}/getField",
        params = "field",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = "text/xml; charset=utf-8")
@ResponseBody    
public String getField(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable final String id, @RequestParam final String field ) throws Exception  {
    Record rec = this.recordRepository.findOne(id);
    if ( field.equals("content") ) {
        return rec.getContent();
    } else if ( field.equals("metadata") ) {
        return rec.getMetaData();
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Wrong field value!");
    }
}
```

But stil not sure if it is the right way.
Thanks.